# Spring Cloud Kubernetes application does not detect when it is running in a pod

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-kubernetes

**Expected Behavior**

According to the Spring Cloud Kubernetes documentation, all that is necessary for a Spring application to detect when it's running in a pod is to add Spring Cloud Kubernetes to the classpath with the `spring-cloud-kubernetes-all` dependency.

This triggers two events:

1. If present the `application-kubernetes.yml` profile is loaded.
2. The Kubernetes implementation of `DiscoveryClient` is used for service discovery, leveraging KubeDNS instead of the default of Eureka.

This environment awareness is described here:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-kubernetes/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#kubernetes-profile-autoconfiguration

and here:

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-kubernetes/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#discoveryclient-for-kubernetes

**Actual Behavior**

After booting the Spring Cloud Kubernetes application using the following yaml and accessing it's actuator endpoint at `http://minikube-ip:port/actuator/env` via a NodePort, I see there are no active profiles set, even though a `application-kubernetes.yml` exists in the `resources` folder:

```
{
"activeProfiles": [],
...
```

Upon further investigation in the `http://minikube-ip:port/actuator/info` endpoint, I see that the Spring application isn't aware it's in a pod at all, as evidenced by:

```
{
    "kubernetes": {
        "inside": false
    }
}
```

**My Code**

*SpringCloudGateway*

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class Gateway {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Gateway.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(p -> p.path("/captcha").filters(f -> f.stripPrefix(1)).uri("lb://captcha").id("captcha"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

*SpringCloudGateway build.gradle*

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'idea'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version '1.6.1'
    id 'com.diffplug.gradle.spotless' version '4.5.1'
}

ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Hoxton.SR5'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway"
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-all'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
    testImplementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server"
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:$springCloudVersion"
    }
}
```

**SpringCloudGateway application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8760

spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      enabled: false

eureka:
  client:
    enabled: true
    registerWithEureka: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_SERVER:http://localhost:8761/eureka}

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

**SpringCloudGateway application-kubernetes.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      enabled: true
eureka:
  client:
    enabled: false
```

**SpringCloudGateway deployment.yml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  generation: 1
  labels:
    run: gateway
  name: gateway
spec:
  replicas: 2
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: gateway
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        run: gateway
    spec:
      hostname: gateway
      containers:
        - image: gateway-image
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          name: gateway
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8760
              protocol: TCP
```

**Logs of the SpringCloudGateway pod**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.6.RELEASE)

2020-12-06 17:15:11.468  INFO 1 --- [           main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: [BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-configmap.gateway.default'}]
2020-12-06 17:15:11.507  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.example.gateway.Gateway         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-12-06 17:15:17.627  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'service-registry' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
2020-12-06 17:15:18.358  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=2ddf218c-a309-33c9-a6e4-7f9ba9a5c5f9
2020-12-06 17:15:19.199  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-06 17:15:19.212  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration$ReactiveLoadBalancerConfig' of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration$ReactiveLoadBalancerConfig] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-06 17:15:19.217  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'deferringLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction' of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.DeferringLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-06 17:15:20.700  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2020-12-06 17:15:20.700  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2020-12-06 17:15:20.722  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2020-12-06 17:15:20.722  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2020-12-06 17:15:28.046  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [After]
2020-12-06 17:15:28.046  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Before]
2020-12-06 17:15:28.047  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Between]
2020-12-06 17:15:28.047  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Cookie]
2020-12-06 17:15:28.047  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Header]
2020-12-06 17:15:28.047  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Host]
2020-12-06 17:15:28.048  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Method]
2020-12-06 17:15:28.048  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Path]
2020-12-06 17:15:28.048  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Query]
2020-12-06 17:15:28.048  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [ReadBodyPredicateFactory]
2020-12-06 17:15:28.049  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [RemoteAddr]
2020-12-06 17:15:28.049  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Weight]
2020-12-06 17:15:28.049  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [CloudFoundryRouteService]
2020-12-06 17:15:29.685  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 18 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2020-12-06 17:15:30.893  WARN 1 --- [           main] ockingLoadBalancerClientRibbonWarnLogger : You already have RibbonLoadBalancerClient on your classpath. It will be used by default. As Spring Cloud Ribbon is in maintenance mode. We recommend switching to BlockingLoadBalancerClient instead. In order to use it, set the value of `spring.cloud.loadbalancer.ribbon.enabled` to `false` or remove spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon from your project.
2020-12-06 17:15:30.974  WARN 1 --- [           main] eactorLoadBalancerClientRibbonWarnLogger : You have RibbonLoadBalancerClient on your classpath. LoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction that uses it under the hood will be used by default. Spring Cloud Ribbon is now in maintenance mode, so we suggest switching to ReactorLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction instead. In order to use it, set the value of `spring.cloud.loadbalancer.ribbon.enabled` to `false` or remove spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon from your project.
2020-12-06 17:15:31.303  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2020-12-06 17:15:31.981  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2020-12-06 17:15:32.390  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2020-12-06 17:15:32.390  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields (file:/app/libs/xstream-1.4.11.1.jar) to field java.util.TreeMap.comparator
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2020-12-06 17:15:33.180  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2020-12-06 17:15:33.181  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2020-12-06 17:15:34.185  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2020-12-06 17:15:34.253  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
2020-12-06 17:15:34.253  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
2020-12-06 17:15:34.258  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
2020-12-06 17:15:34.263  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
2020-12-06 17:15:34.264  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
2020-12-06 17:15:34.266  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: true
2020-12-06 17:15:34.266  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2020-12-06 17:15:34.735 ERROR 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
        at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar:1.9.21]
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:196) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar:1.9.21]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:167) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar:1.9.21]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar:1.9.21]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar:1.9.21]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar:1.9.21]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar:1.9.21]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar:1.9.21]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar:1.9.21]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar:1.9.21]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar:1.9.21]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar:1.9.21]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar:1.9.21]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar:1.9.21]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar:1.9.21]
        at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar:1.9.21]
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1081) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar:1.9.21]
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:995) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar:1.9.21]
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:438) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar:1.9.21]
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:282) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar:1.9.21]
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:278) ~[eureka-client-1.9.21.jar:1.9.21]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:67) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:316) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:359) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:389) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:186) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:356) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getTargetObject(EurekaRegistration.java:129) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient(EurekaRegistration.java:117) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:499) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e39a6809.getEurekaClient(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:38) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:894) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:129) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at com.example.gateway.Gateway.main(Gateway.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:605) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:440) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
        at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
        ... 75 common frames omitted

2020-12-06 17:15:34.738  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2020-12-06 17:15:34.748 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_GATEWAY/gateway:gateway:8760 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server
```

As you can see, it's still trying to connect to Eureka.

*Versions*
Spring Cloud: Hoxton.SR5

Jib

Minikube: 1.15.1

K8s: 1.19

Java: 11

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Very unclear docs on the subject of load balancing with Spring Cloud Kubernetes: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/issues/530

Comment: manually applying the `application-kuberntes.yml` profile does not resolve the issue either. nor does applying the the `cluster-admin` role to the pod resolve the issue. the `/actuator/info` endpoint still returns `{kubernetes { inside: false }}`

Comment: NOTE: This repository recognizes that it's in a K8s cluster on first boot and behaves as expected: https://piotrminkowski.com/2020/09/10/spring-cloud-kubernetes-load-balancer-guide/

Comment: It works when run with `skaffold dev --port-forward`, but not with `k apply -f ./k8s`. Very strange. Will diff the skaffold vs kubectl environments to try to hunt down the reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the application.yml, application-kubernetes.yml, and build.gradle combo that finally worked for me:

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
    implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-all"
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
    testImplementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server"
}
```

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      loadbalancer:
        enabled: false
      enabled: false
    gateway:
      routes:
        - predicates:
            - Path=/**
          id: r-core
          uri: lb://r-core

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_SERVER:http://localhost:8761/eureka}

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include:
          - mappings
          - env
          - health
          - info
```

application-kubernetes.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    loadbalancer:
      ribbon:
        enabled: false
    discovery:
      locator:
        enabled: true
    kubernetes:
      loadbalancer:
        enabled: true
      enabled: true

eureka:
  client:
    enabled: false
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you should have `spring.cloud.kubernetes.enabled=false` in your application.yml? If I understand the docs correctly, you need to leave it to the default value (true) in order for it to do the detection and load the `kubernetes` profile.

If you disable it, it will never load your application-kubernetes.yaml, so setting it to true inside that file will have no effect.

As I understand it you can turn off kubernetes features (e.g. `spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.enabled=false`) in your main YAML, but not the entire k8s integration if you want profile autoconfiguration to work.